# jquery ui droppable insert text in textarea at mouse pointer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag and drop into a textarea using jquery ui draggable/droppable. I set the textarea as droppable. I am able to fire off events when the drop happens but I can't figure out how to determine exactly in which position in the textarea the 'drop' took place.

Basically I would like to insert text at the precise position in the textarea where the drop took place.

Google isn't helping me right now and it makes me sad.

Example:

```
<html><head><title>Drag Drop Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
      appendTo: "body",
      helper: "clone"
    });

    $( "#mytext" ).droppable({
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.position);
        // figure out where in the textarea this is
        // drop in some string
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
</body>

<div id="products">
  <div id="catalog">
    <h3><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h3>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Lolcat Shirt</li>
        <li>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
        <li>Buckit Shirt</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<textarea id="mytext" cols="60" rows="20">Just some random text.</textarea>

</body></html>
```

So, in the above example, how do I find out which position in the textarea a 'drop' happened of one of the catalog li elements and then how do I put in a string into the textarea at that exact position?

Meaning, if I drag 'Lolcat Shirt' into the #mytext textarea and drop it between 'random' and 'text' I would like the #mytext textarea value to change to 'Just some random Lolcat Shirt text.'

Is this possible? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bubba, did you ever get this issue figured out? I'm having trouble determining by your comments, but was just wondering. If so, could you please let me know? My email is in my profile... Thank you!

Comment: Connor, no. It doesn't work. That is, the browsers will let you natively drag and drop text into textareas, but I couldn't find a way to tie that in with jquery ui drag and drop components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really easy in browsers except IE, because you have to work with ranges, and other browsers does'nt have any methods that work with coordinates inside a range(what you need, to place the text there).

But somehow you try to reinvent the wheel. Most browsers(maybe all) allow to move selected text into a textarea, so what you have to do is: onmousedown select the text of the  `<li>` (instead of making it draggable)

Comment: Wow. That was actually really helpful. Yeah. I couldn't find a way to do it via jquery but selecting the text onmousedown and then letting the browser deal with the drag and drop into textarea works. at least in firefox. thanks.

Comment: Could you help me out a little bit more @Dr.Molle ? How do I make the innerHTML of the `<li>` the selection and not the element itself ? Care to share a little code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want absolute coördinates you need to try something like

```
ui.helper.offset().left;  //X
ui.helper.offset().top;    //Y
```

Comment: True. I can get the absolute position on the page. How can I figure out which position in the textarea those coordinates are?