# how to drop div text within a textbox jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggable div. I can drop it on a textbox and call myDroppableTextBox.val(draggableDiv.text()) and that works fine... (i can append and prepend as well)

But, how do I drop the div text into the text box at the place where the mouse is hovering? (instead of prepending,appending, or replacing the text)

Comment: So your asking how to drop it so that the value of the div is inbetween text ie where your mouse in within the textbox?

Comment: How us some code, so we can help you more

Comment: is what you're looking for a click and drop kind of application?

Comment: Is this the question you're asking? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4131808/289832